# Is there a U(1) version of the Toric Code?

Tags: condensed-matter, gauge-theory, topological-order

I know of $\mathbb{Z}_n$ versions of the 2D Toric Code and also 3D versions, but I was wondering if there's a simple lattice gauge theory model with rotors instead of spins placed on each link of a square lattice such that it is a U(1) analogue of the Toric Code model i.e., has anyons and a ground state degeneracy on the torus.

Comment: Yes, that is the U(1) lattice gauge theory. But since it is gapless, the ground state degeneracy is not well defined.

Comment: @EverettYou What I meant was, is there a gapped lattice gauge theory with U(1) such that it is topologically ordered? Or is your statement that all U(1) lattice gauge theories in 2D are gapless? If so, is there a reference where I could read about this?

Comment: No, deconfined U(1) lattice gauge theory is always gapless in any dimension. I don't think you need a reference. Deconfined U(1) gauge theories are just Maxwell equations, and we all know Maxwell equations admits gapless photon mode.

Comment: U(1) gauge theory in 2+1 acquires a gap, this was one of Polyakov's big results.  See his book: "Gauge fields and Strings", for some more details.